# asp.net c# javascript drag and drop file upload not working in Firefox 45

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file-upload, drag-and-drop

Since Firefox updated to v45 yesterday my drag and drop file upload is not working anymore. Is this an error in Firefox or do I have to make some changes to my code? Chrome still works fine, also IE, Edge doenst work also.

This is my code in aspx file:

```
function handleDragOver(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
}
function handleDnDFileSelect(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();    
    files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    var form = document.getElementById('form1');
    var data = new FormData(form);

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 && xhr.responseText) {

            window.location.reload();
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', "customerDocuments.aspx");
    xhr.send(data);
```

This is the code in my code behind file

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;

    for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile upload = fileCollection[i];
        string filename = upload.FileName;
        string newFileName = Regex.Replace(filename, " ", "_");

        if (!filename.Equals(""))
        {
            if (newFileName.IndexOf('\\') > -1)
            {
                newFileName = Session["path"].ToString() + newFileName.Substring(newFileName.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            }
            else if (newFileName.IndexOf('/') > -1)
            {
                newFileName = Session["path"].ToString() + newFileName.Substring(newFileName.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                newFileName = Session["path"].ToString() + newFileName;
            }

            upload.SaveAs(newFileName);
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any kind of error message for showing us?

Comment: No, sorry, there is no error message. It has only stopped working in Firefox.